# Are there any restrictions on which component in MVC that can hold a reference to?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

As the title says:

Are there any restrictions on which component in MVC that can hold a reference to?

Can a view hold a reference to a controller? And so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The View must have a reference to the Controller so that it can execute methods on the Controller when the user performs actions.

The View should also have a reference to the Model so that it can update itself when the Model changes.

The Controller has references to the Model and the View. Typically these are references to *Interface* types to allow them to be mocked during unit testing.

---

Side note: I personally prefer the [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) pattern as I feel it can be easier to test. In an MVP application, the View is a very, very thin layer that barely requires testing at all. The Controller does all the work and can be well-tested using a mocked View and Model.